# What does DrRacket mean by reverse video in the definitions window (after pressing Run)?

Tags: racket

I've written a small module in Beginning Student Language.  When I click Run, some expressions in the Definitions window are highlighted in reverse video (red text on a black background).  I can't figure out which expressions are chosen or what the reverse video means.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the colour preferences, it indicates code that the tests didn't cover:

[image: HtDP colour preferences]

Comment: And the toggle to enable/disable the coloring is the "Syntactic test suite coverage" option in the language dialogue menu (bottom left).